# MongoDB Kafka Sink Connector - postprocessor post.processor.chain class not loading

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, classname, mongodb-kafka-connector, post-processor

We are trying to implement Custom Postprocessor for Kafka MongoDB Sink connector.
However, we are getting classname pattern not found error.

sink-connector.properties
post.processor.chain=yyyy.kafka.mongodb.sink.postprocessor.xml.XMLParserPostProcessor

We are getting same error. Has anyone faced similar error before (class name pattern not found)

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):
Invalid value [yyyy.kafka.mongodb.sink.postprocessor.xml.XMLParserPostProcessor] for configuration post.processor.chain
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:115)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:118)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):
Invalid value [yyyy.kafka.mongodb.sink.postprocessor.xml.XMLParserPostProcessor] for configuration post.processor.chain
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`

Answer (score 0):

Changed the **attributeMappings** field to **Public**. The app configurations loaded from system properties. This resolved the issue.